# Can I make eclipse's task pane not show low priority tasks?

Tags: eclipse, task

When I'm coding, I often find it useful to take advantage of the `// TODO` task feature built into eclipse. I recently discovered I can assign priorities to my various tasks, both the built in ones and my custom ones.

So this is great. However, I would like to hide my low priority tasks from my task view sometimes, focusing only on high and normal priorities. I can kind of achieve this by sorting by priority, but if I do this I lose the sorted by path as well, which means that tasks that are grouped in the same file and package are not really grouped anymore.

tl;dr Can eclipse hide low priority tasks from it's task view? If it can't is there a plugin I can get that does that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure the contents of the Tasks view using its dropdown menu (small rectangle in the top right corner of the view). Select the Configure contents... option from the menu.

Then you could set conditions what to display (e.g. priority).

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much. I didn't even know there was a little menu there. I'm sure the answer to many more potential questions on the topic is also found in that menu. :-)